# How to dynamically change colors of a layerlist in a selector?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, layer, shapes

I am using a listview. Each row has a fancy layout with different press states, shapes and layers. In the adapter of my listview, I would like to set a particular color to these states according to the list row content. The particular color I would like to change in my adapter for each row is the on in the file "**list_row_pressed.xml**" (see below, almost at the end, on line android:color="@android:color/blue" )

The xml for each row is in an xml file "**list_child.xml**"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlLevel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
android:background="@layout/list_rowbg" >
...
```

"**list_rowbg.xml**" is another xml file containing my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@layout/list_row_pressed" >
     </item>

<item 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@layout/list_row_notpressed" >
     </item>
```

"**list_row_pressed.xml**" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />           
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Top Shadow -->
<item android:top="@dimen/rowShadow">
    <shape> 
        <solid

            android:color="@android:color/blue" /> <-- I WANT TO SET THIS COLOR DYNAMICALLY

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="@color/grey"  />
    </shape>
</item>
```

So how can I change in my listview adapter the color "@android:color/blue" in my file "**list_row_pressed.xml**" ?

Thanks